# Converting the code into a function and link problem

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem maybe it is simple .. I hope for your help

This code below shows a graph.

```java
public class LineChartSample extends Application {
 
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
         xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
       
        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
                          
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Portfolio 1");
        
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 23));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 14));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 24));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 36));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 22));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 45));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 43));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 17));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 29));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 25));
        
        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("Portfolio 2");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 33));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 34));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 25));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 44));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 39));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 55));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 54));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 48));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 27));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 29));
        
        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("Portfolio 3");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 44));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 35));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 36));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 33));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 26));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 22));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 25));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 43));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 44));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 45));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 44));
        
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);       
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
       
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
 
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**But I want to divide this code into a function .. when I call it, it executes the code and the graphic appears**

I tried many times, but there are links in the code and I do not know how to collect them, especially in the main part and the stage and scene part

I hope for help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can extract three function from you code.

First is `XYChart.Series getSeries(seriesName)` which return a Series object with filled data.

Second is `getScene(lineCharts,width,height)` which return a Scene object with added series.

Third is `showScene(stage)`, in this method you setup your stage with the above method and call `stage.show()` to show the stage.